# What is the best way to place vinyl laminate in this room layout

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I am replacing the old linoleum flooring in my kitchen with vinyl planks. This is certainly one of the most involved renovations I have done (first home owner and up until now I've only replaced some electrical outlets and installed a ceiling fan in a 3 season room.)

My kitchen is roughly shaped like a rectangle with a protrusion on one side where it joins the front entryway. What I did not realize is that on the West side, the north/south running wall is 95" while on the East side of the protrusion it is 97".

```
       ______ N ____
W 95" |      \./    | E 97"
      |_____________|
              S
```

I began laying the planks working on the west side as that was where I was able to clear all appliances from first. I currently have 6 rows of planks in position, and started laying out some scrap pieces to gauge where to begin the 7th row, which would crest the protrusion and run the entire length of the kitchen (~20'). It was at this point that I discovered that 2" spacing along the East side of the North wall. Would it be acceptable to cut the planks down to 2" width and run along that ~7' wall?

In the images below, the first is where I had started (the orientation of the planks encourages laying them from NE -> SW, as I will have to shift some furniture / appliances from the East side to West side half way through).

I have not removed the existing trim or put spacers down for the 2nd half, but taking those into account, the planks would need to be cut to a 2" width to fill that gap.

[image: Starting Point]
[image: Ending Ponit]

Comment: how does the spacing turn out on the south wall?

Comment: The last plank, continuing from the installed portion on the west side, will need to be cut to 4" width. They are 6" x 48" planks.

Comment: you could still shift all of the planks in the top picture by 2"

Comment: While that is technically true, I already have 10' x 3' of planks laid down including fit pieces around the door jam on the west wall. Certainly, better planning would have helped avoid this, but would a 2" wide plank still be viable?

Comment: 2" wide plank is just fine ... if you slide it under the baseboard, then it can probably be wider